# Accessing google drive api with java throws com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401

Tags: java, google-drive-api

My Request-URI works fine in OAuthPlayGround but my code gives me an error with an exception com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized.

[image]

I have checked the 'request' on OAuthPlayGround and it gave me this response,

[image]

But when tried to execute it on eclipse, I am still facing 401 error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

401 means that the Access Token you are passing is not valid. You need to check and debug your code to see what the Access Token is being set to.